# Why is such a $G$ compact ?

Tags: compactness, symmetric-groups, group-actions, topological-groups

Let $G\leq Sym(X)$ ($Sym(X)$ is the group of permutations of $X$, with the product topology) be a closed subgroup, such that every $G$-orbit is finite.

I want to show that $G$ is compact (I've already proved the converse, and I read somewhere that the two were equivalent); but I've got no idea how to do it. I've tried several characterizations, but each time I get stuck with essentially the same problem: I never get a single $x$ for which I could use the hypothesis; in other words the most obvious things don't work.

I would like it very much if you could provide a hint or so; but not a complete solution (if possible; sometimes a hint amounts to a solution)

Comment: What is the topology on $X$? (I suppose "with the product topology" means that on $Sym(X)$ we consider the subspace topology induced by $X^X$, is that right?)

Comment: @DanielFischer : Discrete topology on $X$ and yes indeed, subspace topology of the product topology on $X^X$

Comment: Good. So, a) what subsets of $X$ are compact, and b) what subsets of a product of Hausdorff spaces are compact?

Comment: @DanielFischer a) finite subsets of $X$, b) subsets of products of compact subspaces ? So I would have to show that each projection of $G$ is finite. But a projection of $G$ on index $i$ is precisely the $G$-orbit of $i$. Ok, I think I got it, thanks a lot !

Comment: @DanielFischer (if what I just said is right, it means that I had a terrible representation of these groups in my head so thanks a lot for your help, it will really change how I see these groups I think, for more than just this question)

Comment: For b), the subset needs to be closed. So you still need to show that $G$ is closed as a subset of $X^X$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : yes obviously, closed subsets. But you gave me the main idea, the rest are just details that I can work out on my own !